# Partial Man on the End Security

Tags: authorization, drm

**The Situation:** I'm developing a script that runs in a popular sandbox game as a paid service for other developers. The problem is that the game does not implement a way to do so. The language is Lua and the game has disabled bytecode loading. This means that any script I hand over to the other developers would have to be executable code.

**The Threat Model:** The developers can access and modify the script's source code. They can setup servers to run scripts on their own computer or on the game owner's server. All scripts run on a server, and never on the player's computer.

**Current Solution:** My code can load string source code and contact an external server through HTTP. I think that my best bet is to contact the external server who can check which type of server I'm running on and deny access if the request isn't from a official game server. I trust the official game servers. Once this is done my script can run the service transmitted to it.

If developers can edit my source code and in order to run the service I need a string to load, what is to stop the developer from printing the string right before I run it? I could use all the white box cryptography I want, but that endpoint of loading a string is still vulnerable. Do any of you security experts have an answer or experience on projects like this?

Comment: I'm confused by your threat model. "I'm developing this as a paid service for other developers" implies (to me) that the other developers are _supposed_ to get access to the code, and so they should be able to run it where they want. Who's the "game owner", and why should it be run on their server (instead of the one of the people who pay you)?

Comment: As the service owner I want to reserve the power to shut off the service if they do not pay and prevent others who have not paid from using the services. If a developer has access to the code and can change it at will, he or she can take out that logic and give it to others or just not pay.

Comment: Who's the "game owner"? The company that made the game?

Comment: Yes, it is the company that made the game. I trust them.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goals with two methods:

1. offload logic into servers controlled by you. Lots of games do this already.
2. obfuscate your code. You can use [XFuscator](https://github.com/mlnlover11/XFuscator), for example.

However, with 2, its impossible to be 100% secure. Preventing people from actually running your code by themselfes and not a server is actually quite impossible.